# MongoDB as a session backend for Django

Tags: django, mongodb, django-sessions

Are there any good packages for using MongoDB as a session backend in Django?

[mango](https://github.com/vpulim/mango/) looks outdated.
[django-sessionbackend-mongodb](https://github.com/loxq/django-sessionbackend-mongodb) is not pip installable and undocumented.

There's also MongoEngine that should work well, but it's overkill in my case.

Any other good options?

Comment: `django-sessionbackend-mongodb` looks pretty good to me. It shouldn't be too hard to repackage it. A session backend really is not that complicated to come up with, reading the source of those included in django should give you a good idea as to how it's done.

Comment: The lack of any documentation is the more serious issue.
https://github.com/martinrusev/django-redis-sessions is a good example of how a "good" package should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoengine,
it supports django 1.4 and quite easy to use.

Read more about it from [here](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html)

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, I think it's a bit too much in my case. Though I like the fact that well tested and documented.